# moving R-project to AZURE

Tags: azure

I'm not very skilled on Azure, but googling hasn't give me more answer on this topic.

I have an ASP.NET web page that use R-(D) COM Interface for doing some complex calculus. I'm evaluating to move everything to the Azure platform.

I saw that it's easy to move webpages on Azure however being that I need that RSERVER is installaled on the machine I need to move everything.

I was thinking of creating a VHD machine and publish the entire image on Azure but I'm not sure this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with RSERVER, but here are some guidelines you may follow:

- By default all Windows Azure servers run in 64bit mode. This is
  important for the COM interfaces.
- You may run *any* executable as a [Startup Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) in regular
  Windows Azure Web/Worker role. Frankly you can create vey complex
  startup scripts. You may use the [Windows Azure Bootstrapper](http://bootstrap.codeplex.com/) to
  ease the solution. The trick is that RSERVER must support
  unattended/silent install.

I would stick to the least friction solution - which would be using a normal Windows Azure Web Role and a Startup Task.

If that is not working for you, you may consider preparing a VHD image and use the [Windows Azure VM Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433107.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've written a very similar answer to what I'd write to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978888/running-existing-program-on-windows-azure-cloud-platform/7982538#7982538). The thing is, the Azure VM role is technically a good solution, depending on what you need to do with it. You can generally create really good solutions with a fairly minimal amount of effort to let legacy code work with Azure & all the shortcomings of the VM role.

In general, if you have a lot of custom installation you need to do, create the Azure VM role, absolutely. But make sure you make the communication with it proper. It's not going to behave exactly like a web or worker role. Although, if I remember correctly, you still have endpoints and configuration there, so you can expose your programming to the outside. Personally however, my architectures are way more queue based (as described in the answer highlighted above) so I'd opt for writing a *bridge* program in the VM.