# Running existing program on Windows AZURE cloud platform

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

i have an existing program that i would like to upload to the cloud without rewriting it and i'm wondering if that is possible.
For exemple  can i upload and run a photoshop instance in the cloud and use it?
Of course not the GUI but photoshop has a communication sdk so web program should be able to control it!

As far as i can see, Worker roles looks good but they have to be written in a specific way and i can't rewrite photoshop !
Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

As long as your existing program is 64bit compatible and it has installer that supports unattended/silent install; or your programm is xcopy deployable, you can use it in Azure.

For the programm that requires installation and supports unattended/silent install you can use [StartUp Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx).

For the program that is just xcopy deployable, just put it in a folder of your worker role, and make sure the "Copy to Output" attribute of all required files are set to "Copy always". Then you can use it.

However the bigger question is, what are you going to do with that "existing programm" in Azure, if you do not have API-s to work with.

Comment: What will happen if my program try to access a file on the disk? Or if my program want to write some stuff in a log ? I guess this will end up with an error? For instance i tryed to open a file in w+ mode in php on azure platform ( with fopen) and it didn't work. I bet it s going to be the same problem here, no?

Comment: On a side note, the programs can normally work with the hard disk, there's quite a lot of it available. It's just that the data doesn't necessarily stay there when the machine is rebooted.

Comment: You can certainly write to the disk. However you have to use Local Storage Resource - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx 
You can, also use arbitrary log files and you can configure Windows Azure Diagnostics to transfer these log files to your Azure Storage Account.
I will update here if I get information how get access to Local Storage resource from within PHP.

Comment: To access the Local Storage Resource, you can use **microsoft-windowsazure-roleenvironment** class from Windows Azure SDK for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing, the Worker role should be what you need - it's essentially a virtual machine running a slightly different version of Windows, that you can RDP to, and use it normally. You can safely run more or less anything up there, but you need to automate the deployment (e.g. using startup tasks). As this can prove a bit problematic, Microsoft has created a Virtual machine Role. You create your own deployment and that's what gets raised when you instantiate the machine.

**However!** This machine is stateless, meaning that files it creates aren't saved if it gets restarted. So you need to ensure the files are saved somewhere else, e.g. in blob storage (intended for just such a purpose).

What I would do in your case, is create a virtual machine role, with Photoshop installed, and a custom piece of software next to it, accepting requests via Azure Queues, that does the processing, and saves the file to blob storage, then sends the file onwards to whoever requested

Comment: I can't use Virtual Machine Role because i have an account through bizspark wich limits me for that.  But i'll try to silent install it and see, the process then would me My program load an image from the blob storage onto the disk of my worker. My program tells photoshop what to do. Photoshop Save the file and notify my program. My program update the old file in the blob storage.  how to send the program tothe worker role online? Is there a way to install this worker roll in the local emulated app fabric?